# iPad screen doesn't respond on corners and types on its own after dropping it

Tags: ipad, screen

My iPad's screen has been buggy ever since I dropped it 2 months ago. It was bearable back then but now it moves the icons by itself and types on its own.

The iPad does not respond to touch on all four corners and whenever I leave it it types on its own and moves the screen.

I have not tried fixing it as I wouldn't want to risk it and break it completely, although I am willing to repair if needed.

Answer (score 2):

The digitizer (the part that senses touch) was damaged in the drop. It will likely need the digitizer replaced. Not sure if that is replaceable separately or of you have to replace the whole screen assembly but that is what needs to be done, no way around it.

Comment: You can replace the digitizer separately on all iPads. The first iPhone and the newer iPhones (4 and later) require a digitizer assembly: digitizer and LCD.